# Can I update my jb 4s to 6.1.2 without restore?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, software-update

I had tried to update (unsuccessfully) several times before yesterday's 6.1.3 release & now I do not want to restore is there a way to get my jailbroken phone to just update?

Any help would be appreciated -  thank you!

Comment: Currently @ 5.0.1 last JB was absinthe

Comment: Do you desire to remain in a jailbroken state, reverse the jailbreak and then update? It's not clear why you don't just restore things and update without more details as to what you're looking to solve. You also didn't edit in what iOS level the phone is at presently.

Comment: Won't the restore process automatically update me to 6.1.3? I'm currently running 5.0.1.

Comment: Apple's tools will let you restore to down level versions in some cases (Xcode) but iTunes wants always to go to the latest or the current version on the device. You might also need to add information about the Jailbreak software you have access to and what computer OS for this to be answerable.

Comment: I have windows XP - sorry I thought you were talking about my phone...

Comment: Is it possible to un- jailbreak my phone? If so, I can just update to 6.1.2 that my iTunes is currently correct?  I am afraid if I try to restore it will bring me up to 6.1.3

Comment: Restoring will update to the latest iOS (with iTunes there is no option not to) and unjailbreak. You may, however, be able to do this: http://www.saurik.com/id/12 although you'd be lucky

Comment: Pooks - please edit in all the details from the comments here so your question reads like you've done your research. We have a guide on asking questions at [ask] as well as the general [faq]. You'll likely get more up votes when you have enough details for people to find the question useful for them (as well as increase the chance people will see it and answer better than I have already).

Answer (score 1):

To state the obvious - you should be able to restore the phone to factory new condition in iTunes, but that would require you to have a backup or sync of the content.

It's hard to know what state things are in with a jailbreak and then a failed installation - but as long as the device is mechanically sound and the jailbreak didn't change the loading software iTunes or Xcode would wipe things and restore it to an un-jailbroken status with the latest iOS installed.

At that point you could use it - but it's not certain if/when/how you would jailbreak again. You might find it easier to attack backing up the content you care about rather than trying to patch together another jailbreak or partial upgrade - but hopefully someone else can help with more first hand experience on jailbreaking and the current iOS levels.

Answer (score 1):

So far, it dosent seem possible to update to a firmware that isent the newest one (6.1.3). You could try updating to 6.1.3, then using redsn0w to make a tethered jailbreak with 6.0.0, but that might cause issues. I would watch a tutorial on that though. My iPhone has also bricked. If I were you, I would wait until there is a new untethered jailbreak for 6.1.3 or until iOS 7 comes out. Sorry to break the bad news to you . :/